# 1+1, 2+1, 3+1... dimensional equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I know it's an easy question, I'm sorry about that.

What exactly are 1 + 1 dimensional, 2 + 1 dimensional, 3 + 1 dimensional... equations?
I must study 1+1 schrödinger equation and NLS equation but I'm a little confused about dimensions.

I think, $u=u(x,y,t)$ may be 2+1 dimensional and +1 part is because of time (t). Is it true?

And can we say that 1+1 dimensional is 2 dimensional? I think that the 2 + 1 dimensional expression is actually 3 dimensional, but we write 2+1 to indicate $time (t)$.

Can someone explain to me what I need to know? I would appreciate it if you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The +1 is time. Thus the independent variables considered together in, say, a 2+1 dimensional model live in a 3 dimensional space, but when considering time separate from space it makes sense to write it as 2+1, to emphasize that the spatial dimension is $2$ but the dynamical problem is under investigation.

I find this terminology is most common in situations where the static version of the problem is frequently considered (so that, for example, the 2+1 dimensional problem can be succinctly distinguished from the 2 dimensional problem).